# Matching arrays with identical unique values VBA (Excel)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, intersection

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now. Originally I had searched Google and found some examples of (more or less) what I am trying to do, but seem to be stuck on the code I have thus far. Essentially I am trying to compare the unique variables between two arrays and return a result when there is a perfect match (if one possesses unique values there represent a subset of the other, this would not be a perfect match, all values and number of values would have to be identical.

From the code I have included below; if I compare one array [range("B2:b6") with values {1, 2, 3}] to a second array [(range("D10:D11") with values {1, 2}], I receive a positive match. Per what I am trying to do however (and value order doesn't matter) the only perfect match within an array of {1, 2, 3} would be a second array with values {1, 2, 3} also (or {3, 2, 1} as order doesn't matter).

I am guessing it is due to the type of array I am using and the fact that the lowerbound starts at 0. I could also be completely wrong. I have tried playing around with it without success.

Any Thoughts? Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks! (included pics with different values below)

[image]

```
Function UniqueVal(ByRef Arr1, ByRef Arr2)

    If TypeOf Arr1 Is Range Then Arr1 = Arr1.Value2
    If TypeOf Arr2 Is Range Then Arr2 = Arr2.Value2

    Dim e, x, i As Long

     With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For Each e In Arr1
            If Len(e) Then .Item(e) = Empty
        Next
        For Each e In Arr2
            If .Exists(e) Then
                .Item(e) = 1
            Else
                .RemoveAll
                UniqueVal = .Keys
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next

        x = Array(.Keys, .Items)
        .RemoveAll
        For i = 0 To UBound(x(0))
            If x(1)(i) = 1 Then .Item(x(0)(i)) = Empty
        Next
        If .Count Then UniqueVal = .Keys
    End With

End Function

'and the below sub which calls the above function

Sub iTestIntersectionX()

array4 = Join(UniqueVal(Worksheets("arrayTest2").Range("B2:B6"), Worksheets("arrayTest2").Range("D10:D11")), vbLf)
Worksheets("arrayTest2").Range("H20").value = array4

If Worksheets("arrayTest2").Range("H20").value <> "" Then
   MsgBox "Match Found!"
  Else
   MsgBox "No Match Found!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the values you're working with always going to be coming from ranges?

Answer (score 1):

This will return True if the two ranges passed in have the same set of unique values (in any order or frequency)

```
Function HaveSameValues(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
Dim c As Range

    For Each c In rng1.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 And IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
            SameValues = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next c
    For Each c In rng2.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 And IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
            SameValues = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next c

    SameValues = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When a range is a continuous column, the question can be solved with this formula:

```
LET(Target;B2:B6;Reference;D10:D11;AND(IFNA(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Target;Target<>"")))=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Reference;Reference<>"")));FALSE)))
```

If the range is different than a 1-dimensional array, I would use this code:

```
Function HaveSameUniques(Target As Range, Reference As Range) As Boolean
Dim TargetUniques As New Collection
Dim ReferenceUniques As New Collection
Dim Cell As Range
    HaveSameUniques = False     ' return False by default; we can drop this line
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Target
        If Len(Cell) <> 0 Then
            TargetUniques.Add Key:=Cell.Value, Item:=0
        End If
    Next Cell
    For Each Cell In Reference
        If Len(Cell) <> 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            TargetUniques.Add Key:=Cell.Value, Item:=0
            If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Function    ' if Target doesn't have Cell.Value, then exit and return false
            ReferenceUniques.Add Key:=Cell.Value, Item:=0
        End If
    Next Cell
    If TargetUniques.Count = ReferenceUniques.Count then
        HaveSameUniques = True
    End If
End Function
```